# Is it possible to combine all test suites in one html file when selenium server is in parallel mode?

Tags: automated-tests, report, nightwatch.js, browser-automation

I'm using `nightwatch.js` and `nightwatch-html-reporter`. I set configuration according to `README.md` file and it looks like this:

```
let reporter = new HtmlReporter({
openBrowser: false,
reportsDirectory: "reports",
uniqueFilename: false,
separateReportPerSuite: false
```

})

```
module.exports = {
reporter: reporter.fn
}
```

The `report.html` file is generated correct for one test suite, but when i'm running all my test suites there is only report of the last running test suite. Regardless of the result.
Any idea how to fix this?